# Associated types which are distinct for each instance

Tags: types, rust

Is there a way to specify associated types in rust which are distinct for each instance? Or is there any plan to introduce it to the language? Or any other way to implement this behavour? I think scala has this feature.

I need this feature for example to define types which represent indices to slices, which do not need to be ranged checked. I don't know the syntax for using this feature, if it exists. So i will use the one i would have expected to work in the following example.

```
// Each safe index has to implement this trait. 
pub trait SafeIndex {
    // Convert the safe index to an unsafe index.
    fn to_unsafe(&self) -> usize;
}

// Safe indexable
pub trait SafeIndexable {
    // The Item which is indexable.
    type Item;

    // In this context self.Index should be usable as index
    // without the need to do a range check.
    // This is a type alias which is distinct for each
    // instance. Therefore you need to specify an instance
    // (self) instead of a type name (Self) to access the type.
    // It is known, that each self.Index implements SafeIndex.
    type self.Index : SafeIndex;

    // Iterator of indices usable without range checking.
    type self.Indices : Iterator<Item = self.Index>;
    fn indices(&self) -> self.Indices;

    // Get item from index, without range checking.
    fn get<'s>(&'s self, index: self.Index) -> &'s Self::Item;
}

impl<I> SafeIndexable for &[I] {
    // The Item which is indexable.
    type Item = I;

    // This is a struct which is distinct for each
    // instance. Therefore you need to specify an instance
    // (self) instead of a type name (Self) to access the struct.
    struct self.IndexImpl {
        unsafe_index: usize,
    }
    impl SafeIndex for self.IndexImpl {
        fn to_unsafe(&self) -> usize {
            self.unsafe_index
        }
    }
    // This is the type alias which is distinct for each instance.
    type self.Index = self.IndexImpl;

    // Iterator of indices usable without range checking.
    struct self.IndicesImpl {
        begin: usize,
        end: usize,
    }
    impl Iterator for self.IndicesImpl {
        type Item = self.Index;
        fn next(&self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
            if self.begin != self.end {
                let cur = self.begin;
                self.begin += 1;
                Some(Self::Item{unsafe_index: cur})
            } else {
                None
            }
        }
    }
    type self.Indices = self.IndicesImpl;
    fn indices(&self) -> self.Indices {
        self.IndicesImpl{begin:0, end: self.len()}
    }

    // Get item from index, without range checking.
    fn get<'s>(&'s self, index: self.Index) -> &'s Self::Item {
        unsafe {
            let ptr = &self[0] as *const I;
            &*ptr.offset(index.unsafe_index as isize) as &Self::Item
        }
    }
}
```

There are tons of even more useful usecases for this feature. Growable only vectors for example.

Comment: Perhaps you should make a feature request on the rust site.

Comment: I'm confused as to which feature you are missing... this can easily be done in rust already: http://is.gd/UhyPOe You just need to define and implement the "self.X" types outside of your trait impl

Comment: @ker That doesn't make a unique type each time. That allows eg. [this](http://is.gd/ishvT8).

Comment: @Pentagolo FWIW, you [can make this a bit prettier](http://is.gd/NpR55F). I don't think what you're asking for is possible, though.

Comment: ah I understand now... You cannot generate a new type from a variable really... The lifetime of the variable is the only thing that differs, and there's no way to test equivalence of lifetimes afaik

Comment: Ok, so its not possible in rust at the moment. But are there any rfcs discussing such a feature?

Comment: @Veedrac Yes, some portions of your code seem to be a bit prettier. Thx. I will try to edit my initial post.

Comment: @Uwe Allner Yes, if there does not exists such a feature request, i will try to write one. It's a shame i did not heard of rust before it was stable. Adding features like this now will likely intotruce inconsistencies.